# Magento 500 Internal server error

Tags: magento2, error

After installing magento on my localhost. It will show an error 500 internal server error and in index.php also have an error on following line -

```
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
```

and in app folder bootstrap.php file also have an error on following line -

```
\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::populateAutoloader(BP, []);
```

Comment: Paste the full stack trace

Comment: Please open bootstrap.php and uncomment line no.11 and run localhost.

Comment: Its still giving an error 500

Answer (score 0):

Try to change permission folders below to 777

> - app/etc
> - var
> - pub/media

And change permission files below to 644

> - index.php (project root folder)
> - download/index.php

Then force deploy static contents

> - php bin/magento setup:static-contents:deploy -f

Finally flush and clean cache

> - php bin/magento cache:clean
> - php bin/magento cache:flush